# `imakeindex` does not print index

Tags: imakeidx, makeindex

## My problem

The following code does not produce the index as expected.I work on Windows 10 in TexStudio and Miktex. I compile to a pdf with pdfLatex. (Thanks, JamesT).

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{imakeidx} 
    \makeindex
    \begin{document}
        Entry 1 \index{Entry 1} and Entry 2 \index{Entry 2}
        Index here
        \printindex
    \end{document}
```

The code produces an .idx file with content. The log says:

*runsystem(makeindex "index testen".idx)...quotation error in system command.*

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It compiles on my TeX Live 2023 Windows 10 and on Overleaf, what versions of TeX are you using, on which system and how are you compiling the document? Could you edit that information into your question please

Comment: By compiles I mean prints the index, too late to edit it the comment

Comment: dont use spaces in your file name

Comment: There were spaces in the name of the file. The are removed now. No result as far as I see.

Comment: There were indeed spaces in the name of the file. The are removed now. No result as far as I see. An .idx file is built with the content as expected. The logfile says "runsystem(makeindex testen.idx)...executed safely (allowed"

Comment: Hm, I have the same message in my logfile AND a printed index on page 2 with your code ... // Sometimes my TexMaker needs a gentle "View PDF" click to show it ...

Comment: Thank you. I think the spaces in the title of the file caused the problem. I see no problem now.